# Order of (S)CSS rules in an Angular application

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I am currently trying to understand some details about the SCSS compilation and inclusion logic in Angular applications. If you take a look at the given [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-2wi6lt?file=theme.scss), you will see that I have included the Angular Material styles.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
...
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

Also, at the bottom of the file, I try to override the height of the Material button.

```
.mat-raised-button {
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

However, this rule is not applied. Or more precisely, it is overridden by the Angular Material styles. **I understand, that I can solve the issue and increase the specificity of the selector or by using !important, but this is NOT what I want**. I want to understand why the rule is overridden given that

1. the selectors have the **same specificity** and
2. the override rule is **written below** the include of the material theme

It seems that angular rearrange the SCSS or includes them differently. In the final result, the override rule ends up before the include of the angular material styles (or is in a completely different file?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is bundling part of the component style with the component itself. That's also the case with material components.

If you look at the `head` of your application, you will notice multiple `style` tags. Each one corresponding to a component, as well as a first one usually the theming css.

For you, that means that the override style you including in the theming css file, will be including first. Then the button is imported by your app, and with it the corresponding css.

Css properties have an order priority, the latest value for each property is the one actually apply by the browser.

You have a couple options to solve this.

**!important**

Brutal but efficient, will apply the style regardless of priorities.

```
.mat-raised-button {
  line-height: 50px !important;
}
```

**Better selectors**

You can add your own class to the buttons and use said class to have a more precise selector, giving you priority.

```
<button class="my-button" md-raised-button>Basic</button>
```

```
.my-button.mat-raised-button {
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

**Style encapsulation**

By moving the style override inside your component, Angular style encapsulation will kick in and make sure that your own style gets priority by adding an attribute selector

```
/* app.component.css */
.mat-raised-button {
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Put the css in app.component.(s)css is not a real solution. If your app.component contains the router and button are in other component, your style still overriden. I'm not sur there are an elegant solution, else namespace your css, like body.my-style { material override }